# text-center for input-group-addon breaking

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a text input and some input-group-addon elements attached to it.  It looks by default, but when I try to center align with text-center, only the input moves over but not the input-group-addon which stays left aligned and looks completely wrong.

I tried center-block but it does even less (doesn't center either components).  I tried wrapping in other divs but no luck.  I am very new to css so apologies if this is very obvious!!

```
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"></span>
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2"></span>
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3"></span>
    <input id="password-input" type="password">
    <button id="password-submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m0L2cofg/2/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're not adverse to using a little CSS, I'd recommend turning the `input-group` into a block-level element, and the `input-group-addons` into inline elements. This way you can center them on `text-center` with `margin: 0 auto`.

I've also given the last one a bit of `margin` to the right to give it an equal offset to the submit button in the following example:

```css
.text-center {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.text-center .input-group {
  display: block;
}

.text-center .input-group-addon {
  display: inline;
}

.text-center .input-group-addon:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"></span>
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2"></span>
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3"></span>
    <input id="password-input" type="password">
    <button id="password-submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Ok cool this does work, thanks!  I just have this weird feeling like we just hacked bootstrap?  Is this a legit way to solve this problem?

Comment: Ehh, if it solves the problem, I'd call it a 'legit' way; Bootstrap is just a framework for you to build on, and you will find that you'll be making modifications to it **often** :) I've personally never needed to use `input-group` myself, but by default it's a `table` that's used in conjunction with two `inline-block` elements. It seems logical to have them all as inline elements :)